# Resource manager for restful service

Tags: rest, wcf, soa, transaction

I was just brought onto a project with a service oriented architecture. There is a central WCF "profile service" that all projects call to get information on users etc.

That central profile service in turn calls several other leaf services to CRUD user information.  One of those leaf services is a third party service that is RESTful.  Part of my responsibility is to add transactions to the central profile service such that update and delete operations on the leaf services either all succeed or all fail.

For most of the leaf services, a relational database is used and so using transactions is straightforward.  For the leaf service that is RESTful, I'm not sure how I can implement a resource manager for it.  I think the very nature of RESTful services makes it impossible to be transactional.

How I can make calls to a RESTful service more [ACID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID)ic?

Comment: https://www.google.co.uk/?q=distributed%20transaction%20wcf

Comment: Sorry I should have been more specific.  I am using distributed transactions for all the services that I control.  There is one RESTful service provided by a 3rd party that I do not control.  I am asking how I can implement some sort of transaction around using their service.